# Django - usage of redirect_to_login

Tags: python, django, url, authentication

I want to use `redirect_to_login` in my view. For some reason, I get redirected to login twice (and therefore the URL is malformed).

My `TestView(View)` looks like this (relevant part):

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.test_func():
        if self.redirect_to_login:
            return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path())
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

My `urls.py` (relevant part):

```
url(r'^test/$', TestView.as_view()),
```

When I type `localhost:8000/test/` into my browser, I end up at

`http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/%3Fnext%3D/test/`

instead of expected

`http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/test/`

Any ideas what the problem might be? In case you need more files, just please ask.

Comment: try using `self.request.get_raw_uri()` instead of full_path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this `/%3Fnext%3D/test/` is equal to `/?next=/test/` you just need to pass the word `test`. In the return should be something like:

```
return redirect_to_login('/test/')
```

More information about `redirect_to_login` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#helper-functions